# EhCache @Cacheable Throws Exception When Sync

Tags: java, spring, synchronization, ehcache

When calling a method annotated with `@Cacheable` with the sync flag set to true, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.get(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason a library was setting the spring-context-support version to 4.2.x instead of 4.3.x in my build. This caused the synchronous get method to not be implemented. Make sure your spring-context-support library is at least at 4.3.